# let the sets $A,B\ne \phi$, and $f:A\rightarrow B$, and $F(A)=\{ b\in B \mid \exists a\in A : f(a)=b \} $ , is this statement correct?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

let $X,Y\subset A$ (subsets of A), then $F(X)\cup F(Y)=F(X\cup Y)$. 

My attempt: intuitively it seems right and I tried to get a counterexample but all of them have worked. so I tried to proof: 
 let $y\in F(X)\cup F(Y) \Rightarrow y\in F(Y) \bigvee y\in F(X) $, from here on, I'm wondering how to continue, should I say that there exists $x\in X$ or $x\in Y$ such that $f(x)=y$, then proceed to show that it is $\in F(X\cup Y)$? feels like I kinda have the idea but I lose it while proving it.

any explanation or assistance is really appreciated.

Comment: You are correct. What about the reverse direction?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I also tried it its the same idea just wanted to see if what I'm thinking about is correct, my problem is that I get stuck while proving with the (or) in between and would like to see how it's formally done

Comment: Well $x\in X\text{ or }x\in Y\implies x\in X\cup Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we prove that $$F(X)\cup F(Y)\subseteq F(X\cup Y)$$  Let $z\in F(X)\cup F(Y)$.  Then $z\in F(X)$ or $z\in F(Y)$.  Suppose the former.  Then $\exists x\in X$ such that $F(x)=z$.  But $x\in X$ implies that $x\in X\cup Y$, so also $z\in F(X\cup Y)$.  We can make a similar argument if we suppose instead that $z\in F(Y)$.

Now for the reverse inclusion, we proceed similarly.  Let $z\in F(X\cup Y)$.  Then $\exists a\in X\cup Y$ such that $F(a)=z$.  But $a\in X\cup Y$ means that $a\in X$ or $a\in Y$.

Can you finish it from here?